# Not all tiles loading in view (web) with Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

For some reason, my map does not load all the tiles when viewed on the web. Here is a link to the test data - http://bestersurveys.co.za/htmlsite/maptest.html

I have nothing funny in my code and really can't find a solution on the net, so can someone help me out?

Source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.35.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.35.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    #fly {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background: #ee8a65;
    }
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<br/>
<button id='fly'>Fly</button>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2VhbmRyYWFkbG96ZSIsImEiOiJjajA3cW1pOTcwMDA5Mndvd2hicHlmNWc1In0.7bt7sPXDoymYJyVDvVmqZw';
var start = [24.543,-32.254];
var end = [24.536281,
      -32.248698];
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/seandraadloze/cj1d6b9ri00eb2son1z7ejrhl',
    center: start,
    zoom: 13.8
});

var isAtStart = true;

document.getElementById('fly').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // depending on whether we're currently at point a or b, aim for
    // point a or b
    var target = isAtStart ? end : start;

    // and now we're at the opposite point
    isAtStart = !isAtStart;

    map.flyTo({
        // These options control the ending camera position: centered at
        // the target, at zoom level 9, and north up.
        center: target,
        zoom: 18.9,
        bearing: 60,
        pitch: 60,

        // These options control the flight curve, making it move
        // slowly and zoom out almost completely before starting
        // to pan.
        speed: 0.4, // make the flying slow
        curve: 1, // change the speed at which it zooms out

        // This can be any easing function: it takes a number between
        // 0 and 1 and returns another number between 0 and 1.
        easing: function (t) {
            return t;
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4587.

Try downgrading to Mapbox GL JS 0.34.0 until a fix for that issue is released.